# update one database from another without overwriting notes

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table in my database

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Family` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Last_Name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`His_F_Name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`Her_F_Name` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`address` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`city` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`phone_number` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`Notes` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

I would like to update this list from a csv file which was exported from a different database based on the id's.  That is, if the records with  the same ID have different adresses or phone numbers, what I have should be overwritten by what is in my csv file.  However, I do not want to overwrite the `Notes` field, and if there is a record in a different table that references one of these records I do not want to mess up the link.

(How) is it possible to do this?  Using phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use phpmyadming csv file import feature (Import->Format(choose csv)) or
   Use [BigDump](http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/) to import csv-data to your MySQL
2) Use following query

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE Family f
        INNER JOIN
    FamilyTEMP ft ON f.ID = ft.ID 
SET 
    f.address = ft.address,f.phone_number = ft.phone_number;
```

First line turns of safe update so you can update your table without using primary key condition.